# How to modify elements of Ruby Array composed of Frozen String Literals

Tags: ruby, string, immutability

Given a file

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

alphabet = %w(a b c)
alphabet.each do |letter|
  letter << 'suffix'
end
```

How can one modify the individual elements of the array if the individual elements of the array are frozen string literals by default?  Is there a way to make `letter` mutable?  I tried to prepend a unary `+` in the each block like so: `alphabet.each do |+letter|`.  Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frozen objects can't be unfrozen. But you can build new objects from them.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

alphabet = %w(a b c)
alphabet = alphabet.map do |letter|
  letter + 'suffix'
end
```

Comment: Or `alphabet.map! { |letter| letter + 'suffix' }` is there's a need to modify the array in-place.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to unfreeze an object. That would defeat the point of freezing it in the first place.

The first question I would ask myself is: if you need to modify those strings, why do you freeze them to begin with? That makes no sense. If you *absolutely must* modify them, then don't freeze them.

However, I am not a big fan of mutation anyway, so I would suggest an immutable solution instead:

```rb
alphabet.map { |letter| letter + 'suffix' }
```

If you insist on using mutation and cannot change the creation of those strings to not be frozen, then Ruby offers you the [`String#+@`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-2B-40) method which returns a non-frozen *copy* if the string is frozen, and simply the string itself if it isn't.

So, you could do something like

```rb
alphabet.each do |letter|
  +letter << 'suffix'
end
```

Except that won't work because you create a *copy* of the string and modify that copy, but you are not doing anything with the copy, you are not returning it, not storing it anywhere, not assigning it to anything, not passing it to any method. It will simply vanish.

You could do

```rb
alphabet.map do |letter|
  +letter << 'suffix'
end
```

but again, you are not modifying the strings in the array and instead create new ones, you are creating a new array, so what's the point in creating the mutable copies?

You could do

```rb
alphabet.map! do |letter|
  +letter << 'suffix'
end
```

Which would mutate the *array* and not the strings inside it.

It is quite simply impossible to get the same semantics that you would get from mutable strings, unless well, the strings are mutable from the beginning (duh!)

So, if you were to start your program with something like this:

```rb
alphabet.map!(&:+@)
```

Then it would work the way you want to:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# frozen_string_literal: true

alphabet = %w(a b c)
alphabet.map!(&:+@)

alphabet.each do |letter|
  letter << 'suffix'
end

alphabet
#=> %w[asuffix bsuffix csuffix]
```

But I would always prefer an immutable, purely functional, referentially transparent, total solution if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
arr.freeze

arr << 'd' #=> FrozenError (can't modify frozen Array)
arr[0] = 'd' #=> FrozenError (can't modify frozen Array)
arr[1].replace('e') #=> ["a", "e", "c"]
arr.frozen? #=> true

arr array is frozen means you can’t change the array. But the strings inside the array aren’t frozen. If you do a replace operation on the string “one”, mischievously turning it into “e”, the new contents of the string are revealed when you reexamine the (still frozen!) array
```